# Visual Studio 2015 - Multiple Versions in Multiple Windows Won't Build

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build

I use the Microsoft Recommended way of structuring my solutions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668992.aspx

Typically I work off the main branch, and occasionally I open a older release. When I'm working I often have the Main branch open in one VS window, and an older release open in the other, something like this:

- Visual Studio Window 1 - Main Solution(Solution containing: Web Site with several other Main Class Libraries)
- Visual Studio Window 2 - Release 2.0.0(Solution containing: 2.0.0 Web Site with several other Version 2.0.0 Class Libraries)

Often times when I have both windows open, Visual Studio becomes confused between the two of them. For example, I build the 2.0.0 version of my website and then attempt to build the main site, the main site build will fail referencing a missing object that clearly exists within the project but not in the older version(2.0.0):

[image]

(Reference exists in Main branch, but not in 2.0.0)

[image]

My work around to this issue is to close both Visual Studio windows and then reopen only the main branch, rebuild, and everything works correctly.

It appears as though Visual Studio is confusing the two projects. Is there a way to get around this issue without closing both windows?

### Update 1

I've tested this on VS 2017 and it doesn't seem to be occurring, I've also changed my folder schema since I first encountered this behavior.

Comment: You use git? In the same physical location?

Comment: @DotNetDev I use TFS, the TFS server is on separate server.